# using open() to read file and then using specific lines in if statement python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a login system in python atm.
I got so far that I can register a user and create a .txt file with the username and password in two different lines.

[textfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBfcR.png)

But when it comes to the login system I've run into a problem. I can read the textfile, but when I'm using these two different lines in an if statement using:

```
    try:
        #usr is the username given in the login process by the user(the name of the
        #created file is always the name of the user)
        data = open(usr + ".txt", "r")
      
        l = data.readlines()
        #l[0] is reading the first line of code and the iam comparing
        #them to the username and password given by the user 
        if l[0] == usr and l[1] == pss:
            print('LOGED IN')
        else:
            print('WRONG')
     

    except Exception as e:
        print('Error reading file')
```

**I am using the latest version of python and I am running on LinuxPopOs**

*my whole code:*

```
import time
print("LOGIN -> 1")
print("Register -> 2")
print("")

select_ = input("")

if select_ == '2':

    print("Username:")
    usernamee = input()
    print("Password:")
    passworde = input()

    print("Type ""y"" to register or ""n"" to cancel")
    forward = input("")
    if forward == 'y':
        #creating database
        data = open(usernamee + ".txt", "w")
        data.write(usernamee + "\n")
        data.write(passworde)
        data.close()


    else:
        print('closing...')
        time.sleep(2)
        exit(0)

elif select_ == '1':
    print("LOGIN:")



    usr = input("Username:")
    pss = input("Password:")

    try:
        #usr is the username given in the login process by the user
        data = open(usr + ".txt", "r")
      
        l = data.readlines()
        #l[0] is reading the first line of code and the iam comparing
        #them to the username and password given by the user 
        if l[0] == usr and l[1] == pss:
            print('LOGED IN')
        else:
            print('WRONG')
     

    except Exception as e:
        print('Error reading file')







else:
    print(select_ + "is not valid")
```

Thanks

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.

Comment: Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; we need your question to be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: `readlines()` keeps the newlines in the lines. You need to strip them off.

Comment: What is the problem with this code?

Comment: I understand that you're just trying to get something together but please realize that storing user/pass info in an unencrypted file is a security risk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be that white space and/or newline characters aren't being stripped from the strings read by `readline`.  Changing the `if` statement to strip trailing characters should rectify that, e.g. `if l[0].rstrip() == usr and l[1].rstrip() == pss:`